# How to get the sum of child component state value in parent component on first load?

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to have a Parent component with state attribute 'sum'.
There are 2 Child components with state attribute 'value' with values 1 and 2 respectively.

On the load of application I want Parent to show '3'.
Currently I'm calling Parent method from Child using componentDidMount(), but in parent after this.setState() the values aren't updating!

```
Child:
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.calculateTotal(this.state.value);
  }

Parent:
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      total: 0
    };
  }

calculateTotal = value => {
    console.log("value ", value);
    const calculatedTotal = this.state.total + value;
    console.log("calculatedTotal ", calculatedTotal);
   this.setState({
      total: calculatedTotal
    });
    console.log(
      "total after setting state",
      this.state.total
    );
  };
}
```

In Parent I expected 'totalValue' to get sum but it is not happening.

Any assistance in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the same in the callback of setState, and new value will reflect. Since setState doesn't happen synchronously, your immediate console.log after setState is ignored.

Check the following, this should do what you're trying to do, I'm using `prevState` param to access the current state instead of doing `this.state.total + value`:

```
calculateTotal = value => {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
      total: prevState.total + value;
    }, () => {
      console.log("total after setting state", this.state.total);
      console.log("This callback will show the new value");
    }));
    console.log("This will NOT show the new value", this.state.total);
  };
}
```

Hope this is helpful!